# Prefix and Suffix issue

Tags: suffixes, latin, prefixes

My question is simple, is there a known reason why the word "prefix" has only one "f" but the word "suffix" has two, "ff"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These words are 'borrowed' from Latin, which routinely performed [*elision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) and [*assimilation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(linguistics)) on prefixes with a final consonant when the consonant was sufficiently similar to the initial consonant of the root to which it was attached. The resulting word was spelled with a doubling of the remaining consonant.

> pre- + fix- ... no final consonant, so *prefix*
> sub- + fix- ... so *suffix*
> ad- + fix- ...  *affix*
>
> in- + toler- ... {n} and {t} are very high contrast, so *intolerant*
> in- + med- ... *immediate*
> in- + lum- ... *illuminate*

The same pattern is followed with modern coinages using Latin prefixes and roots.